# Explanation of the definition of an Extreme point of a Convex Set

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, definition

I find the definition a bit ambiguous (perhaps I am missing something).

The definition goes as follows:

A point $\textbf{x}$ in a convex set $S$ is said to be an extreme point of $S$ if for no distinct $\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2\in S$, $\textbf{x} = \lambda \textbf{x}_1 +(1-\lambda)\textbf{x}_2, \lambda\in (0,1)$

Now, what if the set $S$ is open? How does the definition hold up?.

My textbook says another version of it:

A point $\textbf{x}$ is said to be an extreme point of a convex set $S$ if for no distinct $\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2\in S$, $\textbf{x} = \lambda \textbf{x}_1 +(1-\lambda)\textbf{x}_2, \lambda\in (0,1)$

This seems even more ridiculous (perhaps I am mistaken, again). Because according to this definition, any point lying outside of $S$ is entitled to be an extreme point (i.e. doesn't even need to be a boundary point).

Can some explain what am I missing?

Comment: What is the context? Are we talking about convex subsets of $\mathbb R^n$? Or of something else?

Comment: @LeeMosher in $E^n$

Comment: For your question when $S$ is open, in that case $S$ has no extreme points; I see no contradiction or problem with that. For your question about comparing the two versions of the definition, they seem absolutely identical to me **except** that in the second version the condition $x \in S$ seems to have been dropped; and as you say, they are not equivalent when that condition has been dropped. But this leads me to wonder where you found these two definitions. Were they in the same textbook? Is there some missing context?

Comment: @LeeMosher former one is from Wikipedia. Another one is from my textbook.

Comment: @LeeMosher , so extreme points must be contained in the concerned set?

Comment: I would have to see the context surrounding that definition in the textbook. It could be a simple mistake in the textbook; or it could be that there is some missing context and $x$ is assumed to be in $S$; or it could be something else. It's very hard to guess without more context.

Comment: @LeeMosher There is no prior assumption/context in my book.

Answer (score 3):

What I have been taught, is a more positively stated version, basically equivalent to your first: $p \in S$ is an extreme point of $S$ when

$$\forall x,y \in S: \forall t \in [0,1]: (tx + (1-t)y = p) \implies t\in \{0,1\}$$